# Move Subfolder up one level including its contents

Tags: powershell

I need to move a lot of sub-folders.  Each client has this structure and needs to be modified

The only folder I need to move is the "**Correspondence**" folders with all its contents.  It needs to come "up" one level to the same level as the "2022" folder

The current folder structure looks like this:

Clients
........Surname,Initials
................................2022, Prior Years
.................................................................2018
.................................................................2019
.................................................................2020
.................................................................2021
.................................................................Calculations
.................................................................**Correspondence**

and this is what I need

Clients
===>Surname,Initials
===>2022,  **Correspondence**,  Prior Years
.......................................................................2018
.......................................................................2019
.......................................................................2020
.......................................................................2021
.......................................................................Calculations

This is what I have tried

`dir -Directory | % {Push-Location $_.FullName; dir './Correspondence' | % {Move-Item $_.FullName}`  but that didn't work and resulted in errors

`dir -Directory | % {Push-Location $_.FullName; dir './Correspondence' | % {Move-Item $_.FullName}`  That also resulted in errors

Comment: `2022`, `Correspondence` and `Prior Years` are 3 separate folders and are supposed to be "siblings" after the script has done, is that correctly understood?

Comment: Yes the 2022, Correspondence and Prior Years are supposed to be "siblings" but currently the correspondence folder is one level too low

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following locates all subdirectories named `Correspondence` in the current directory's subtree and moves them up one level:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory -Filter 'Correspondence') |
  Move-Item -Destination { $_.Parent.Parent.FullName } -WhatIf
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf`  once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

Note:

- The [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) call is enclosed in `(...)` so that all its output is collected up front, to rule out the possibility of the move operations interfering with the enumeration of the file-system items.
- The `-Destination` argument is provided in the form of a [delay-bind script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks#using-delay-bind-script-blocks-with-parameters), which allows deriving the argument value from the input object at hand, reflected in the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_):

  - The `.Parent` property of the [`System.IO.DirectoryInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.DirectoryInfo) instances output by `Get-ChildItem` reflects the parent directory (as an instance of the same type), i.e. the directory in which the subdirectory hand is currently located.
  - `.Parent.Parent` therefore reflects the parent directory of the one in which the subdirectory is currently located, and `.FullName` property contains its full path.